# Add copy location constraint to each bone, with target empty at same location?

Tags: scripting, constraints

I've got a script that places a empty at each vertex and is parented.

I've got a script that adds a bone to each vertex.
 But I need a script that does a copy location to each bone, and the target must be the empty at the same location.
  Since I've copied and pasted these scripts and know nothing of scripting I'm hoping somebody could help??

Comment: Well, not without knowing what you're after. Why do you need this setup? Why not hook the vertices directly to the empties?

Comment: The vertices are hooked to the empties, I need the bones to follow the empties.  I then bake the bones after I've done cloth sim.  And I can now edit the cloth simply with actions and shape keys.   Here is what I've done manually https://youtu.be/sLobCOYL8pg

Comment: Also here is a link to a forum with the scripts that I use https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?442444-cloth-edit-script&highlight=